# Trouble running a 32-bit VB app under Windows Server 2008 64-bit. Is WoW automatic or not?

Tags: windows-server-2008, 32bit-64bit

I have an application developed by a third party which is written in VB.

It's a 32bit application and the missing DLL's are 
olepro32.dll
and ieshims.dll

Where do I obtain these from?  I want to download direct from Microsoft NOT a third party.

Using dependancywalker I have managed to sort some of the missing files.  Putting 
c:\windows\syswow64 in the path helped for olepro32.dll.
I found a copy of ieshims.dll on the system and copied that to the application path.
Now dependancy walker is showing:

Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

Now what?  I see a long list of modules with a mixture of x64 listed in red and x86 showing black

Solved.  It was caused by Data Execution Prevention.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of VB, and what OS are you trying to run the application on? The VB6 runtime (supporting files for running VB 6 applications) are included in Windows Vista and 7 (and probably earlier), and you can download them here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192461.

Comment: Thanks I found that earlier, but it didn't fully resolve the problem.  I'm trying to run the app under windows server 2008 R2

Comment: Not sure which version of VB but I think it might be VB6